# ERROR 1045 (28000) en mysql

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente error en MySQL al intentar iniciar sesión desde el *CMD* a mi base de datos:

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>mysql -u THEBOSSraul -p
>
> Enter password: *****
>
> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'THEBOSSraul'@'localhost'
>
> (using password: YES)

Comment: Te he puesto la solución espero que te sirva

Comment: y no te olvides de si te funciono votarla positivamente y marcar el check para que se resuelva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1.*** Ve al fichero ***my.ini*** y **con permiso de administrador** ábrelo para editarlo.

En la parte que pone **[mysqld]** añade la siguiente linea.

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

***2.*** Reinicia el Servidor MySQL.

***3.*** Inicia Sesión.

```
mysql -u THEBOSSraul -p
```

***4.*** Modifica la contraseña.

Seleciona la base de datos de **mysql**.

```
USE mysql;
```

**Mostramos las tablas :**

```
SHOW TABLES;
```

**Revisamos la tabla usuarios :**

```
DESC user;
```

**Luego cambio la contraseña con el siguiente comando :**

```
UPDATE USER SET AUTHENTICATION_STRING=PASSWORD('123456') WHERE user='THEBOSSraul';
```

***Salimos del terminal*** del ***MySQL*** y Reiniciamos el servicio

Después reiniciar volvemos al terminal de MySQL y añadimos el siguiente comando :

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'THEBOSSraul'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
```

**Nota :** Este ultimo comando te da permisos sobre todas las bases de datos juntos a sus tabla desde cualquier parte